# FIlter a column based on another column-sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where i count the records based on multiple columns. I have specified a condition to filter only only few types from a column.

Work       Task

```
MR   SERR
TO   SERR
PO   NULL
TO   MEDT
```

In my query i have this condition
WHERE (TASK in ('SERR') or TASK is null)

This is valid for all "Work" except "To". When it counts for "TO", it needs to include all in column "task".

How do i address this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an `OR` condition:

```
WHERE (Work = 'To' OR ISNULL(Task,'SERR') = 'SERR')
```

`ISNULL(Task,'SERR') = 'SERR'` will cover both of your current conditions.